# Getting typeerror

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am working in an application, it is working fine in IE but not in Chrome. While debugging i am getting the below error.

> rpf.js:562 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
>   at afficheBloc (rpf.js:562)
>   at newRequest.do?org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN=5367b965f46acbe85e769f3eff64bab9:7163

`document.getElementById` is the lines where i get typeerror.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < idChampRemove.length; i++){
    removeRequired(idChampRemove[i]);
    document.getElementById(idChampRemove[i]).value="";
}
```

Comment: What does `removeRequired()` do? Because it sounds like it might be removing the element, so it would make sense that it no longer exists when using `document.getElementById` - why it still works in IE is hard to tell without some more of your code. A [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be great!

Comment: Little more details about removeRequired() function and what it aims at will be more than helpful.